# how to make stack executable for educational stack smashing?

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, stack-smash

having this c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void return_input(void){
    char ar[30];
    scanf(" %s", ar);
    printf("%s\n",ar);
}

int main (void) {

    return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

as disassambled:

```
 0x0804919b <+0>:   push   %ebp
   0x0804919c <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804919e <+3>: and    $0xfffffff8,%esp
   0x080491a1 <+6>: call   0x8049172 <return_input>
   0x080491a6 <+11>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x080491ab <+16>:    leave  
   0x080491ac <+17>:    ret
```

I want to run the address `0x080491a1` so to print the output 2 times (just to see it is possible to exe arbitrary address):

```
$ printf "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC\xa1\x91\x04\x08" | ./exe
```

but instead of executing (in book, in what I read [shellcoder handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047008023X) it will input 2 times, so that I am expecting), this arise:
`AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC�� 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

compiled with  `cc -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -ggdb -m32 -fno-stack-protector -o exe -no-pie -fno-PIE exe.c`

How to access the memory address without segfault?

EDIT: added `-z execstack`, but still `segfault`, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the `-z execstack` GCC option. Using it will make the stack of your program executable. You can also use the [`execstack`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack) command line utility to modify existing binaries making their stack executable (or not executable).

Comment: Still `segfault` even with that option on. Should I have a less characters? But I do have buffer of size 30 bytes, then it would not overflow or?

Comment: `AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDD��
Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when `printf "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDD\xa1\x91\x04\x08" | ./exe
`

Comment: @Herdsman your error is somewhere else. Most probably you're not jumping to the right address since the memory address of the stack is usually randomized. Execute the code through GDB one instruction at a time and see what happens.

Comment: @Herdsman your payload also doesn't make sense, it's not shellcode, it's just jumping to a random address `0x080491a1` (assuming you override the return addres with the last 4 bytes).

Comment: as you can see from `gdb disas main`, it is the address of  `0x080491a1 <+6>: call   0x8049172 <return_input>`, so no, the address it right. Could see it even with step by step gdb

Comment: @Herdsman ah, pardon me. Makes sense. The problem is somewhere else then, I don't know precisely where, it's only a matter of debugging.

Comment: It should not have any purpose, it is indeed random jump, but in the book, it was 2 times outputted

Comment: @Herdsman the pipe after `printf ... |` is implicitly telling your program that the standard input is over after that line. Your function will fail to read a second time. I don't know if that's going to work as expected. Try `(printf "..."; cat) | ./exe`, after that I can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: Your question was concerning how to make the stack executable, and so I answered, but that's another problem.